# Iterating through multiple Excel files, Saving specific Cells into a Dataframe using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

**Problem:** I want to iterate though Excel files and pull out specific values and save to a dataframe.

**Why:** This helps a QA process, with a loop I can pull all reports in a folder and save key data points quickly. The current process involves opening each file and copying and pasting certain cells to a 'Master QA' xlsx file

**Example:** We have three files in a folder
[image]

And they all have two data points `Date` and `count` cell `B4` and cell `C4`with the data points

[image: Two data points for each file]

We can print each data point for each file using `openpyxl`

```
import os 
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

path=r"C:\Users\Desktop\StackOverflow"
os.chdir(path)

for resi_files in os.listdir(path):
     if os.path.isfile(resi_files):
                myworkbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(resi_files)
                worksheet= myworkbook['Sheet1']
                print(resi_files)
                print("Date")
                print(worksheet.cell(4, 2).value)
                print("count")
                print(worksheet.cell(4, 3).value)
```

This will give us this output:

[image]

However! This does not do us any good, we want to be able to compare the different cell values for QA purposes. So we need to save these values into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To save to a dataframe** we must do the following:

```
import os 
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np #added to save count as a number

path=r"C:\Users\Desktop\StackOverflow"
os.chdir(path)

merged=pd.DataFrame()
for resi_files in os.listdir(path):
     if os.path.isfile(resi_files):
                myworkbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(resi_files)
                worksheet= myworkbook['Sheet1']
                data = pd.DataFrame(data=[worksheet.cell(4, 2).value], columns= ['Date'])
                data['count'] = np.array([worksheet.cell(4, 3).value])
                    # to grab a different cell, change the 4 and 3 
                    # 4 means 4 rows down, 3 is 3 columns over, not indexed at 0
                merged=pd.concat([merged,data])
```

And by printing `merged` we see we have a dataframe that is easier to work with.

Comment: To be honest I'd suggest you build a table (as a list) of the values in Python and pass this in one go into Pandas.

Comment: By values do you mean `4,2` for `Date` and `4,3` for `count` or the values meaning `File 1.xlsx`, `File 2.xlsx` `File 3.xlsx`?

Comment: I mean create a table like `(Date, File, Count)` with rows accordingly. Build this in Python. You can then create a single dataframe from this. See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html#converting-a-worksheet-to-a-dataframe

Comment: @CharlieClark I'm not sure what you mean. I added what I think you mean below based on the documents using `DataFrame(ws.values)`

Answer (score 0):

The solution Charlie Clark is mentioning above is not quite what I need. I need to grab specific cells, because the Excel document I am using is formatted with a lot of empty cells. However, it is a value solution if you have better formatted Excel sheet. Here is the edited code to fit Charlie's suggestion

```
import os 
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path=r"C:\Users\Desktop\StackOverflow"
os.chdir(path)

merged=pd.DataFrame()
for resi_files in os.listdir(path):
     if os.path.isfile(resi_files):
                myworkbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(resi_files)
                worksheet= myworkbook['Sheet1']
                data = pd.DataFrame(worksheet.values)
                merged=pd.concat([merged,data])

print(merged)
```

This will give us this output in the specifc case mentioned above:

[image]